# Unable to write to a file/give write permission to a file

Tags: permissions, kali-linux

For some reason even when I logged in as root and using "sudo su", I can't write the file of  "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor". `Error writing lock file ./.scaling_governor.swp: Permission denied.`
I has tried to give it the permission to write by .`chmod +w scaling_governor`
nothing apeared, then when I do `ls -l` I got `-rw-r--r--`
Sorry for my English

Comment: How exactly are you trying to write to that file?

Comment: (I ask because that looks like you're trying to use some kind of text editor, which I'd rank as "rookie mistake". And Kali, themselves, say [that if you're a rookie, you should not use Kali](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/))

Comment: I'm using nano, should I just echo in there?

Comment: yes (also, why spend time asking that question when you could try?)

Comment: beacause: `┌──(root㉿kali)-[/sys/…/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq]
└─# echo "ondemand" | sudo /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor   
sudo: unable to execute /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied
`

Comment: what you're doing makes no sense at all. This is independent of the linux distro, but you should *really* not be using Kali, as it's dedicatedly not meant to learn Linux.

Comment: what about `echo "ondemand" /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Comment: is that one correct way?

Comment: you're getting closer, what you'd want is something like `sudo -s`, to get a shell as root, and then redirect (`>`) the output of `echo` to /sys/devices and so on!

Comment: but seriously, you're trying to set a CPU governor on Kali. That probably isn't even an issue you have to deal with on a proper Linux distro – and Kali literally doesn't give you any functionality you wouldn't have on Debian or say Ubuntu. So, maybe just *not* use Kali! That would potentially solve the issue you're trying to solve by fiddling with CPU governors (which, by the way, is one of the things that usually do not work out like one thinks it does), and **again**, would make sense in any use case where you're a beginner.

Comment: output of `sudo echo "ondemand" > "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor "`:`zsh: permission denied: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor `

Comment: It's beacause I'm having trouble with booting ubuntu from usb

Comment: then fix that instead of working on Kali. Using Kali because your Ubuntu USB stick won't boot is like "I can't find the hole where I can put gas into my car, so I'm trying to ride a tank to work today. Why is driving this tank so complicated?".

Comment: See, please, after reading the Kali website I've linked to above, this explanation why it's hard to help you with Kali: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: great simile, I will try debian